# Slick.js autoplay carousel bounces the last slide, then bounces back to the correct slide

Tags: jquery, .net, carousel, slick.js

I am using slick.js carousel with autoplay configuration in my .Net site. On the last slide, it bounces to the previous slide for about a second. Afterwards, it bounces right back to the correct slide.

**Preconditions:**
All files and libraries are included where they should be according to Slick.js and other q&a's in this site

**What was checked:**

- removing / altering autoplaySpeed
- adding dots
- increasing / decreasing slides amount
- implementing in mobile site (works great)
- adding infinity set to true (it is default value anyways)
- removing onerror function
- changing "homeCarousel" class name

**Results:** 
Only when autoplaySpeed is short(1000) - it bounces front and back with no visible systematization

**Markup:**

```
<div class="homeCarousel"> 
    <div> 
    <a href="/Article/QA%20Article%20friendly%20name%20">
<img alt="First image Main Ban\dsvfner " data-alt-source="homepage/fbBg.jpg?v=0" onerror="javascript:common.imageLink.replaceSourceOnError()" src="http://az742468.vo.msecnd.net/images/homepage/fbBg.jpg?v=0">
</img>
</a> 

    </div> 
    <div> 
    <a href="/Article/UFO%20Kfir"><img alt="Third image Main Banner " src="http://az742468.vo.msecnd.net/images/homepage/Kids_main_mnn_MNN.jpg?v=0">
</img>
</a> 

    </div> 
    <div> 
    <a href="/Article/acdascd"><img alt="Fifth image Main Banner " src="http://az742468.vo.msecnd.net/images/homepage/Fathers_day_2015_main_mnn1.jpg?v=0">
</img>
</a> 
    </div> 
    </div>
```

**JS (in another file, bundle):**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        homeCarousel.init();
    });

    homeCarousel.init = function () {
        if ($('.homeCarousel')) {
            $('.homeCarousel').slick({
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2500,
                infinite: true,
                pauseOnHover: true
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: seems to be working ok, I think: http://jsfiddle.net/a15cw3jg/2/

Comment: yes, just not in my project. the problem seemed to be a css class selector capturing all transitions (*). making it more specific fixed it.

Comment: @shanshan What exactly did you change in your code to make it "more specific"? I'm still running into the same problem as you.

Comment: @Bryan hope you solved it. I looked for a "transition: XXs" as TGN12 suggested

Comment: @shanshan Yep, I resolved it, thanks for the followup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Could happen if you set transition on the slick element so when slick tries to show the correct slide your transition set is interfering.

I would look for a "transition: XXs" that is not related to slick

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a css class selector capturing all transitions (*). making it more specific fixed it.